# Wrap Text in UISegmentedControl (iOS 9+)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I've seen a few other questions discussing wrapping text/multi-line content in segmented controls but all of the solutions are either super janky or deprecated since 9.0 (so please don't mark this as a duplicate unless you can cite a 9.0+ post with a solution).

All I want to do is wrap text within a segment to the next line... is there a clean/correct way to do this in Objective-C? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested, but this seems like the rational approach...

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
NSDictionary *attributtes = @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };
[mySegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work although it's exactly the kind of solution I'm looking for. I think I need to modify the numberOfLines attribute of the labels but I have absolutely no idea how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.  I think the attributed text approach is right.  Not sure why it would be resistant to a word-wrap attribute.  See if you can set font family or some other simple attribute using this approach, then we'll have a much more refined question to answer.

Comment: Alright so part of the problem is that we were only setting it for `UIControlStateSelected` but not `UIControlStateNormal`. I was able to change the font correctly so I tried messing with the line break stuff and I noticed one change; with your code, the text doesn't end with an ellipses and is instead cut off by the segment.

Comment: Ok, good.  I think you're nearly there.  Then either bring the point size down on the font or change the segment control frame size in code.  I'd start with the former.

Comment: Well even if I increase the height of the control to well over what it would need for 2 lines, the text still doesn't wrap and decreasing the font size isn't an ideal solution unfortunately. Any other thoughts?

Comment: It must mean that the control's layout doesn't anticipate anything but the standard size.  You could dig through the view hierarchy to get that internal label (or whatever it is) and resize it yourself, but that violates your desire to not hack -- which I very much agree with.  You could roll your own, (its really just a set of buttons after all), or you could just stick to font size.  Have you ever seen a multiline segment control?  I haven't.  That's decent evidence for (a) just being more terse with the text, or (b) roll your own.  I'd go for (a) unless I absolutely couldn't

Comment: I completely agree with all of that... font size it is. Thanks for the help!